Do one-way functions increase entropy?
Let $X$ be any random variable distributed in some way.  Let $F$ be a one-way function.  Then if $H$ is the entropy, is it true that
$$
H(X) \leq H(F(X))?
$$
I get the sense that this should be trivially true for a function to be one-way, but I am not sure about a proof.

HINT: Consider the case where $f$ is a constant function and mayube revise your guess. (Also note: $\mathbb P(f(X)=f(a))\le\mathbb P(f(x)=f(a)|x=a)\mathbb P(x=a)$).

It easily follows from the definition of Shannon entropy that applying any function (one way or not) to a random variable can only decrease (or leave unchanged) the entropy. Things may be different for other notions of entropy, e.g. some definition of apparent entropy. So you should define what you mean by entropy.

You have to be careful about definitions and models here. For any deterministic function the inequality is the other way:
$$
H(f(X))\leq H(X)
$$
by the so-called "data processing inequality".
For your desired inequality to hold, we need to use a formulation which assumes key (or trapdoor) information which is part of the choice of the one way function is hidden from the opponent who observes the output of the function $f$.
If we model a one way function via an independent source of randomness (e.g., a hidden key $K$) which increases the uncertainty about what the input $X$ is given the output $f(X)=f(K,X),$ then
$$
H(f(X,K))\geq H(X)
$$
can hold. In particular when $K$ is independent of $X$ we have
$$
H(K,X)=H(X)+H(K)
$$
where $(K,X)$ is jointly distributed as $P_K(k) P_X(x)$
and if the one way function after its processing "loses" some but not all of the entropy supplied by the key $K$ we get an inequality in the direction you want, the design of the one way function ensuring, e.g.,
$$
H(f(X)) \geq c (H(X)+H(K))
$$
for some constant $c \in (0,1)$ where $K$ is almost uniformly distributed over some large keyspace so that the right hand side is still larger than $H(X).$

I think, the OP's main question/confusion is the proof of data processing inequality. One can keep the entropy by just a constant function, or permutation which suits. Whenever non-linearity enters the game, information is lost implying entropy is lost.
